# Solarized colour scheme in Kile

Tags: latex, text-editor

Is it possible to have a [solarized colour scheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) on Kile for LaTeX? I am using it on all the other editors and interfaces that I have (Python, R, RStudio, Geany and so on) but I could not find anything for Kile. Is there such a possibility at all?

Comment: You should be able to. Do you not see the solarized options in Settings>Configure Kile>Editor>Fonts & Colors?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that is why I was wondering whether I had to import it from elsewhere first.

Comment: Do you have the `konsole4-kpart` package installed? Edit: never mind, that's for Konsole.

Comment: Scratch what I said earlier. Try installing `konsole4-kpart`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, install `kate-data` instead (you can uninstall the other package if you wish).

Comment: I made it work manually concatenating the color scheme to the kate config file, see my answer below. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

I made it work manually concatenating the colour schemes to the kate config files as shown in the "readme" instruction file [here on GitHub](https://github.com/hayalci/kde-colors-solarized).

First concatenate the following

```
cat ./"Solarized Dark.kateschema" >> ~/.kde/share/config/kateschemarc
cat ./"Solarized Light.kateschema" >> ~/.kde/share/config/kateschemarc
```

and then complete concatenating the highlight syntax

```
cat ./"Solarized Dark.katesyntax" >> ~/.kde/share/config/katesyntaxhighlightingrc
cat ./"Solarized Light.katesyntax" >> ~/.kde/share/config/katesyntaxhighlightingrc
```

This does the job. Open Kile and go to:

**Settings -> Configure Kile -> Editor -> Fonts & Colors**

and choose the schema.